QUICK energy calculations in Amber Tools, vs Gaussian 16, vs Open Babel MMFF94
I am just getting back into molecular modeling, and looking for an open-source tool for generating some conformers from various SMILES to use in binding simulations.
Way back when I used Gaussian for single-point energy calculations. Now Open Babel seems to be popular, but I see it uses MMFF94 for organic molecules and when I looked up this method seaching for benchmarking I found this paper  that suggests that the output may not be as reliable as I would like.
I've also found that the Amber Tools package contains QUICK. It says it uses Hartree-Fock and DFT. It looks like it came out in 2021, but I haven't seen any benchmarking done and don't know if it's reliable enough or more reliable than MMFF94, or if I should just continue looking.
Is QUICK a known reliable method for generating starting conformers, or is there an alternate open source or low-cost method that people are using nowadays?

To clarify, are you looking for a tool to generate conformers or a tool to get their energies in order to rank them or compute some property with a weighted average of the conformers? All the programs mentioned do the latter, but based on your first and last paragraph, you seem to be interested in the former.

How will you do the binding study? All the docking software will generate their own library of conformers to run the docking simulations, so, any conformers you previously generated will be “destroyed” in the process.

For clarification, I'm trying to prepare the ligand for Molecular Dynamics simulations, most likely in AMBER, and while AMBER has their own GAFF force field for organic molecules, the antechamber tool used in preprocessing will take the ligand input and modify the GAFF force field if needed based on the ligand file (to my understanding). It needs the RESP charges, which I've only ever had calculated from GAUSSIAN (back when I had access to that suite of software).
Eventually it would be good to understand things like the calculated bond energies to understand the likely ligand stabilities.

From my POV, you only need to optimize the ligand with DFT, calculate the charges you want and then, when creating the input for Molecular Dynamic (MD), tell the system to use the charges from the file. Even when charge distribution can vary from conformer to conformer, if the force field in MD is not polarizable, the charges will be fixed. Also, using several conformers to run several MD will be very time consuming.
